# How to send common (label, value) pair to prometheus?

Tags: c#, .net, prometheus, grafana

I want to create a Grafana dashboard with several plots (each for client) with BitmapValue for Y-axis and time for X-axis.
To send data to Prometheuse there are 4 ways: counter, guage, histigram, summary.
Unfortunantly there is no way to send just data without counters, so I use a hack.
I send BitmapValue = "metric value":

```
my_metric{BitmapValue="1", Name="client1"} 1
my_metric{BitmapValue="2", Name="client1"} 2
my_metric{BitmapValue="8", Name="client2"} 8
```

Are there any legal way to send to Prometheus label/value pair without counters?
Thank you.

Comment: It seems like there is some kind of confusion. Counter - is one of Prometheus' metrics type (that should only increase). I assume you're talking about sending metrics without value (if I'm wrong - correct me please). Then no there is no way of scraping metric without value, but you could use value 1 for all of them (like `node_os_info` for example)

Comment: Could you maybe clearer explain why it is needed? Maybe there is a way to use Prometheus in a more traditional style.

Comment: @markalex, thank you for answer. I want to create plot with BitmapValue for Y-axis and time for X-axis. So i need to make Grafana use BitmapValue as value instead of metric value. I don't find any way to set special value for y-axis in grafana options, by deafault it is metric value. That is why I use that hack.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing that I can imaging base on your description is the way how windows exporter exposes status of services.

Expose all possible bit-values as labels of you metric and use values for metric 0 and 1.

```
my_metric{BitmapValue="1", Name="client1"} 1
my_metric{BitmapValue="2", Name="client1"} 1
my_metric{BitmapValue="4", Name="client1"} 0
my_metric{BitmapValue="8", Name="client1"} 1

my_metric{BitmapValue="1", Name="client2"} 0
my_metric{BitmapValue="2", Name="client2"} 1
my_metric{BitmapValue="4", Name="client2"} 0
my_metric{BitmapValue="8", Name="client2"} 0
```

And later in Grafana use query like

```
my_metric{BitmapValue="1"} * 1 +
my_metric{BitmapValue="2"} * 2 +
my_metric{BitmapValue="4"} * 4 +
my_metric{BitmapValue="8"} * 8
```